# Where to see the result of hook_menu()

Tags: routes

What is the purpose of `hook_menu()`, if I can create menus from the administration pages?

```
function onthisdate_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['blog'] = array(
    'title' => 'blogs',
    'description' => 'Listing of blogs.',
    'page callback' => 'blog_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );
  $items['blog/feed'] = array(
    'title' => 'RSS feed',
    'page callback' => 'blog_feed',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

so now where do I see the result of this function in the admin panel or in the site where the module is rendering?

Comment: are the keys of the arrays an url to add to the menu url in the admin panel?

Comment: looks like yes :)

Answer (score 1):

[hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is the method used by modules to add their own menu items. Most of the menu items you see on Drupal are added by modules with that hook.
The user interface allows you to add extra menu items that are not added by modules.

If you are asking the difference between creating a module that adds menu items with `hook_menu()`, and adding menu items with the user interface, `hook_menu()` allows to do things that are not possible with the user interface. For example, the menu that is visible when you hover the gear icon visible for a block is created with menu items added with  `hook_menu()`. (It requires the Contextual links module, which is a Drupal core module.)

[image: screenshot]

The tabs that you see, for example, on a node page, are created with `hook_menu()`, or `hook_menu_alter()`. You could not create them with the user interface.

[image: screenshot]

What you can create with the user interface are links that go:

- In a menu block

  [image: screenshot]
- In the Menu links

  [image: screenshot]
- In the Secondary links

  [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

it depend on the type. if it is [MENU_CALLBACK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7), then it would not be displayed anywhere; it would be just an internal link.

On the other hand, if it is [MENU_NORMAL_ITEM](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_NORMAL_ITEM/7), it would be displayed in the navigation menu, in the appropriate place depending on the path; for example, if the path is admin/config/regional/language/configure, it would end up as tab for the Languages page.

See also the documentation page for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `hook_menu()` is a way to legitimize a URL within your site. For example you, might need to set up a URL for your AJAX where you'd process data, such as `/my-application/get-ajax-data`. You do that with `hook_menu` - the key for `$items` array is the path you want to define.

The name of the hook may certainly be misleading, as the result might not necessarily be a menu item. But this is how you tell Drupal "Hey, this URL is authorized, no fear to go there." Of course - as it shows in the code you provided - there's the whole access control over it.